# Calculate mean of triplicates using row and column specifier, ignore NAs

Tags: r, loops, mean, na

I would like to make a loop which calculates mean values by row moving by three values and ignoring missing (NA) values.

Here is my example, where mean of a, b and c values and mean of x, y and z should be calculated:

```
df <- data.frame(label=paste0("lab", 1:15), a=1:5, b=6:2, c=25:11,
                                     x=5:1, y=2:6, z=11:25, zz=NA)
df[,2]<-NA
df[1,]<-NA
df
```

And my far-from-complete solution:

```
res <- tapply(df[,2:4], df[,5:7], mean, na.rm=F)
```

Expected outcome:

```
head(res,3)
   label  a  b  c  x  y  z zz mean_abc mean_xyz
1   <NA> NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
2   lab2 NA  5 24  4  3 12 NA 9.7 6.3
```

Comment: when you want to ignore NA, you should use `na.rm = TRUE`. Also. Please try to avoid names for your sample data frame that are reserved for base R functions such as `df`

Comment: How do you come to 11? (5+24) / 2 = 14.5?

Comment: I think, the gist of the below answers is: This is not something one needs a loop for.... nor for loop ... ;)

Comment: Means have been corrected, but these are means of three values (NA + 5 + 24) / 3 =9.7

Answer (score 2):

```
> df$mean_abc <- rowMeans(df[ , c('a', 'b', 'c')], na.rm = TRUE)
> df
   label  a  b  c  x  y  z zz mean_abc
1   <NA> NA NA NA NA NA NA NA      NaN
2   lab2 NA  5 24  4  3 12 NA     14.5
3   lab3 NA  4 23  3  4 13 NA     13.5
4   lab4 NA  3 22  2  5 14 NA     12.5
5   lab5 NA  2 21  1  6 15 NA     11.5
6   lab6 NA  6 20  5  2 16 NA     13.0
7   lab7 NA  5 19  4  3 17 NA     12.0
8   lab8 NA  4 18  3  4 18 NA     11.0
9   lab9 NA  3 17  2  5 19 NA     10.0
10 lab10 NA  2 16  1  6 20 NA      9.0
11 lab11 NA  6 15  5  2 21 NA     10.5
12 lab12 NA  5 14  4  3 22 NA      9.5
13 lab13 NA  4 13  3  4 23 NA      8.5
14 lab14 NA  3 12  2  5 24 NA      7.5
15 lab15 NA  2 11  1  6 25 NA      6.5
```

Comment: the mean of x, y, z should also be calculated, I suggest: df$mean_xyz <- rowMeans(df[ , c('x', 'y', 'z')], na.rm = TRUE)

Comment: or is there a more elegant solution, because the real dataset contains multiple columns?

Answer (score 1):

I admit, by far not as elegant and efficient as @EDi's answer, but here a possible tidyverse solution (I have named your data frame 'my_dat')

```
require(dplyr) 
require(tidyr)

my_dat %>% gather(group1, value1, a:c) %>% 
           gather(group2, value2, x:z) %>%
           group_by(label) %>%
           summarise_at(vars(value1, value2), funs(mean), na.rm = TRUE)

# A tibble: 15 x 3
   label value1 value2
   <fct>  <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 lab10   9.00   9.00
 2 lab11  10.5    9.33
 3 lab12   9.50   9.67
 4 lab13   8.50  10.0 
 5 lab14   7.50  10.3 
 6 lab15   6.50  10.7 
 7 lab2   14.5    6.33
 8 lab3   13.5    6.67
 9 lab4   12.5    7.00
10 lab5   11.5    7.33
11 lab6   13.0    7.67
12 lab7   12.0    8.00
13 lab8   11.0    8.33
14 lab9   10.0    8.67
15 <NA>  NaN    NaN
```

I don't like the double gather step and there is certainly some improvement possible. But it gives the mean of the rows.

Comment: value2 is correct, but in value1 row lab2 should be (NA + 5 + 24) / 3 = 9.7

Comment: Nope. you have two values. so you divide by 2.

Comment: in principle yes, but column 'a' should be taken into account in the mean calculation; so here NA = 0

Comment: this is then not an “NA” value, but would represent a true measurement.

Comment: If you want your NAs represented as value in your calculation (there might be reasons to do so but I wonder which those should be) , then first simply replace your NA with 0

Comment: I agree, but this is a simplified version, so I filled column a with NAs. But when measurements fail it returns NA, which can either be treated as 0 or ignored. Let's say that there are two NAs in column a, but most of the column contains values

Comment: Again, when your measurement fails I would assume that the safest would be to disregard this measurement and treat this as NA, and then the correct mean would be the mean of the remaining measurements. It does not matter how many and where those NA are in which column. mean(na.rm = TRUE) will take care of those.